# Doctrine 2 ODM MongoDB storing images in GridFS from memory

Tags: php, image, mongodb, doctrine-orm, odm

i want to store uploaded files in mongodb as GridFsFile. Im using the doctrine 2 odm. it works fine when i read a file from disk and store it. But what i would like to achieve is to avoid storing the uploaded files anywhere on file system.

Is it possible to store the binary string directly?

Answer (score 1):

According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5077252/php-file-upload-memory-handling-on-cgi), PHP always writes uploaded files to a temporary directory, and the `_FILES` array just points to those uploaded files.

You might consider setting PHP's `upload_tmp_dir` to a directory you've mounted as `tmpfs` or `ramfs` to avoid writing the files to disk. see [here](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/11/overview-of-ramfs-and-tmpfs-on-linux/) for a comparison of the two memory-based file systems.